# Create SQL Database with parameters

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-injection

I have a code in SQL that creates a database using this command:

```
string query = String.Format(
            "CREATE DATABASE [{0}] ON PRIMARY (NAME = N'{0}', FILENAME = N'{1}') LOG ON (NAME = N'{0}_Log', FILENAME = N'{2}') FOR ATTACH",
            dbName, dbFile, logFile)
```

However, this code is exposed to SQL Injection.

Re-writing the above query with parameters did not work, and I understand that DDL commands like CREATE DATABASE does not support parameters.

What is the correct way to write this SQL command in code with dynamic parameters?

I would prefer not to use store procedures as it is a huge change in my code infrastructure.

Comment: what about [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above syntax is product specific.)

Comment: @Jodrell, I tried this but it also didn't except the parameters.
Do you have maybe a working example to share? Thanks!

Comment: @jarlh, I'm using SQL Server

Comment: [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: That code gets susceptible to injection if you let users define the injected values. You let users define database filenames for your database?

Comment: That's not SQL code I assume it's C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote the names you need to use `QUOTENAME` with dynamic SQL.

```cs
const string query = @"
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
CREATE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@dbName) + '
ON PRIMARY (NAME = ' + QUOTENAME(@dbName) + ', FILENAME = ' + @dbFile + ')
LOG ON (NAME = ' + QUOTENAME(@dbName + '_Log') + ', FILENAME = ' + @logFile + ')
FOR ATTACH;
';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
";
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("YourConnectionString"))
using (var comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
    comm.Parameters.Add("@dbName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).Value = dbName;
    comm.Parameters.Add("@dbFile", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 260).Value = dbFile.Replace("'", "''");
    comm.Parameters.Add("@logFile", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 260).Value = logFile.Replace("'", "''");

    conn.Open();
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Two immediate problems, file paths definitely shouldn't be passed through `QUOTENAME`, I'm not sure about the Log and Data names either. Additionally your parameters for the file paths risk truncating valid values.

Comment: Because valid paths don't begin with `[` and a path is not a name. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=376b320927238a555565d8d1126e7946. There is nothing in the question that says the OP will use the name for the path. There are separate parameters for both.

Comment: You didn't use `, ''''` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b5a47a228a5e5c8daf00899b0eff6cc3 I concede your point on the length